# Using traits as types in enums

Tags: enums, polymorphism, rust, traits

Here's my code:

```
trait UnaryOperator {
    fn apply(&self, expr: Expression) -> Expression;
}

pub enum Expression {
    UnaryOp(UnaryOperator, Expression),
    Value(i64)
}
```

Which gives the following errors:

```
error: the trait 'core::marker::sized' is not implemented for type 'parser::UnaryOperator'
note: 'parser::UnaryOperator' does not have a constant size known at compile-time
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish what I want. I've tried:

```
trait UnaryOperator: Sized {
    ...
}
```

As well as

```
pub enum Expression {
    UnaryOp(UnaryOperator + Sized, Expression),
    ...
}
```

And neither solved the issue.

I've seen ways to possibly accomplish what I want with generics, but then it seems like two expressions with different operators would be different types, but that's not what I want. I want all expressions to be the same type regardless of what the operators are.

Comment: *then it seems like two expressions with different operators would be different types* - I think you need to post an example of this; I'm not very sure what you mean.

Comment: Well consider solution 3 in your answer. If I have two different unary operators, `A` and `B`, then some expressions would be `Expression<A>` and others would be `Expression<B>`. These are different types, right? As in suppose I had a vector of `Expression`s. That vector would have to be either a vector of `Expression<A>` or a vector of `Expression<B>`. It couldn't have both. Is that correct?

Comment: Gotcha. As I understand it, you are correct. You *could* create a `Vec<Expression<&UnaryOperator>>`, but there's certainly some extra hassle involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traits do not have a known size - they are *unsized*. To see why, check this out:

```rust
trait AddOne {
    fn add_one(&self) -> u8;
}

struct Alpha {
    a: u8,
}

struct Beta {
    a: [u8; 1024],
}

impl AddOne for Alpha {
    fn add_one(&self) -> { 0 }
}

impl AddOne for Beta {
    fn add_one(&self) -> { 0 }
}
```

Both `Alpha` and `Beta` implement `AddOne`, so *how big should some arbitrary `AddOne` be*? Oh, and remember that other crates may implement your trait sometime in the future.

That's why you get the first error. There are 3 main solutions (note that none of these solutions immediately fix your problem...):

1. Use a `Box<Trait>`. This is kind-of-similar-but-different to languages like Java, where you just accept an interface. This has a known size (a pointer's worth) and owns the trait. This has the downside of requiring an allocation.

```rust
    trait UnaryOperator {
        fn apply(&self, expr: Expression) -> Expression;
    }

    pub enum Expression {
        UnaryOp(Box<UnaryOperator>, Expression),
        Value(i64)
    }
```

2. Use a reference to the trait. This also has a known size (<s>a pointer's worth</s> two pointers' worth, see [Matthieu M.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337719/using-traits-as-types-in-enums?noredirect=1#comment48781345_30338006)). The downside is that *something* has to own the object and you need to track the lifetime:

```rust
    trait UnaryOperator {
        fn apply<'a>(&self, expr: Expression<'a>) -> Expression<'a>;
    }

    pub enum Expression<'a> {
        UnaryOp(&'a UnaryOperator, Expression<'a>),
        Value(i64)
    }
```

3. Use a generic. This has a fixed size because each usage of the enum will have been specialized for the specific type. This has the downside of causing code bloat if you have many distinct specializations. **Update** As you point out, this means that `Expression<A>` and `Expression<B>` would have different types. Depending on your usage, this could be a problem. You wouldn't be able to *easily* create a `Vec<Expression<A>>` if you had both.

```rust
    trait UnaryOperator {
        fn apply<U>(&self, expr: Expression<U>) -> Expression<U>;
    }

    pub enum Expression<U>
        where U: UnaryOperator
    {
        UnaryOp(U, Expression<U>),
        Value(i64)
    }
```

Now, all of these fail as written because you have a *recursive type definition*. Let's look at this simplification:

```rust
enum Expression {
    A(Expression),
    B(u8),
}
```

How big is `Expression`? Well, it needs to have enough space to hold... an `Expression`! Which needs to be able to hold an `Expression`.... you see where this is going.

You need to add some amount of indirection here. Similar concepts to #1 and #2 apply - you can use a `Box` or a reference to get a fixed size:

```rust
enum Expression {
    A(Box<Expression>),
    B(u8),
}
```

Comment: *This also has a known size (a pointer's worth).* => Actually, two pointers' worth, those are fat pointers/references and contain both a pointer to the data part (which is heap-allocated) and a pointer to the v-table (ROM).

Comment: @MatthieuM. ugh! I *always* get that wrong. Fixed now, and thanks!

Comment: @MatthieuM. although, does the data part need to be *heap*-allocated? I know I've seen a trait reference to something that seems to be on the stack like `let f1 = ImplementsFoo::new(); let f2: &Foo = &f1;`

Comment: The data part need not be allocated, the `'a` in `Trait + 'a` refers to the lifetime of the data part actually (the v-table is `'static`).